# Solving for a in a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For which values of $a$ does the system
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1$$
$$x_1 + 2x_2 + ax_3 = 2$$
$$2x_1 + ax_2 + 4x_3 = a^2$$
have (i) a unique solution, (ii) no solution, (iii) infinitely many solutions? Where the system has infinitely many solutions, write the solutions in parametric form.

So I tried to row reduce the matrix and got up till this point:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&1&1\\ 0&1&a-1&1\\ 0&a-2&2&a^2-2\end{array}\right]$$

But I'm a little confused on how to continue further. How exactly would I change the $a-2$ to a $0$ and $2$ to a $1$?

Any help?

Comment: Subtract the second row times $a-2$ from the third. Then divide the third row by the element $3,3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\det \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & a \\
 2 & a & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)=3 a-a^2$

$3a-a^2\ne 0\to a\ne 0\lor a\ne 3$ the sistem has one and only one solution

If $a=0$ the system becomes

$\begin{cases}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3=1\\
 x_1 + 2 x_2=2\\
 2 x_1 + 4 x_3=0\\
\end{cases}
$

Infinite solutions $(t,1-t/2,-t/2)$

if $a=3$ then $\text{rank}(A)=2$

$
A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\text{rank}(A|B)=3\ne \text{rank}(A)$

so the system is impossible

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The discussion depends on the zeroes of the main determinant. Developing with the first column,

$$\Delta=2-(a-2)(a-1).$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track :)

So you have
\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&1\\ 
0&1&a-1&1\\ 
0&a-2&2&a^2-2
\end{array}\right]\\
\xrightarrow{R_3-(a-2)R_2\to R_3}\
&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&1\\ 
0&1&a-1&1\\ 
0&0&2-(a-2)(a-1)&(a^2-2)-(a-2)\\ 
\end{array}\right]\\
=&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&1\\ 
0&1&a-1&1\\ 
0&0&a(3-a)&a(a-1)\\ 
\end{array}\right]\\
\end{align}

Can you proceed from here?

> Consider the cases where $a=0,3$.

Comment: Why should you consider $a=1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust don't we have inconsistent system with $a=1$ or did I make some careless mistake?

Comment: When $a=1$, the unique solution is $x_1=0,x_2=1,x_3=0$.